# Cannot parse double

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to parse values like $15,270.75 with the expression

```
double cost = 0;
double.TryParse("$15,270.75", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out cost);
```

but have no success

Comment: Are you getting an error or not getting the result you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The currency symbol of Invariant culture is not $, its ¤. This works:

```
double cost = double.Parse("¤15,270.75", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You'll need a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) that supports exactly this format.

Answer (score 4):

The following works:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";

double.TryParse("$15.270,75", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, culture, out cost);
```

The culture I used here is en-US for the $ symbol. The reason I manually set the group and decimal separators is because the format used in the input string are different from the culture of en-US.

Maybe you are expecting a specific culture that is not en-US. Try passing that one.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are using InvariantCulture. you need an american CultureInfo

Comment: Americans aren't the only ones who use '$' ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work with CultureInfo.Invariant culture.  Use an appropriate CultureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that works for any locale, use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture for the IFormatProvider parameter.